# Sending a string between two processes using named pipes

Tags: c, ipc, named-pipes

I am trying to send a string, "Hi" from Child1 to Child3 which are two sibling processes. The code runs, however i do not receive the input from Child1 in Child3.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#define MSGSIZE 1024

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    int  fd;
    char * myfifo = "/desktop/myfifo";
    char  l[MSGSIZE];
    pid_t child1, child3;
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
    child1 = fork();

if (child1 == 0) {

    printf("I am Child 1: %d \n", (int)getpid());
            fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
            write(fd,  "Hi", MSGSIZE);
            close(fd);
    } 

else {

    if (child1 > 0 ) {
       printf("I am parent: %d \n", (int)getpid());

        wait(0);
    }

    child3 = fork();

    if (child3 == 0) {
        printf("I am Child 3: %d \n", (int)getpid());

        fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
        read(fd, l, MSGSIZE);
        printf("Received: %s \n", l); 

        close(fd);
    } 
}
    wait(0);
    unlink(myfifo);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: and you didn't think that verify if your pipe has been create correctly will be a good idea ? Always check your syscall ! Error can't be ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're doing non-blocking IO, opening one end of a FIFO will block until the other is also opened. So `child1` blocks in its `open(2)` call until `child3` opens their end of the pipe. However, you're also calling `wait(2)` in the parent process *before* you fork off `child3`.

So you have a deadlock: Parent is waiting on `child1` to fork `child3`, but `child1` is waiting for `child3` to open the other end of the pipe.

You can fix this in at least two ways. First, just put the `wait(2)` call after you fork the second child process. The other way is to create a `pipe(2)` in the parent process, and let the children inherit these descriptors and pass data to each other that way.